# Tracing an inheritance relationship?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, downcast

I am trying to trace some code and the relationship between a parent and child class. The parent class has the following definition:

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {
  private String owner;
  public A(String s) {
    owner = s;
  }
  //More methods related to this class
}
```

Suppose `B` is derived (a child class) from `A` and `B` has a String type instance variable called `landlord`, which also has a getter method (called `getLandlord()`). `B` also has two String parameters in the constructor: `owner` and `landlord`. Would the declaration and constructor of `B` look like this?

```
public class B extends A {
  private String landlord;
  public B(String s, String landlord) {
    super(s); //From parent class
    this.landlord = landlord;
  }
}
```

I also have a method that should return the `landlord` whenever the actual parameter is an instance of `B`. The original code I wrote was this:

```
public static String house(A a) {
  return a.getLandlord();
}
```

This returned a compiler error, and I used casting to try to avoid this compiler error:

```
public static String house(A a) {
  return ((B) a).getLandlord();
}
```

When I write this code:

```
B.house(new A("Johnson"))
```

will I get the String `landlord` because I am using downcasting?

Comment: `((B) a).getLandlord()` will throw a ClassCastException if `a` is an instance of `A`

Comment: @BrandonG I think I understand that, but I have one more question: I'm a little confused because the parent class takes one parameter when the constructor is called, but the child class takes two parameters when the constructor is called. Would this be why a ClassCastException is generated? Is this an inappropriate downcast?

Comment: The number of parameters to the constructors doesn't really matter.  The ClassCastException happens because you pass in `new A("Johnson")`, which is an instance of `A` and cannot be cast to `B`.  To avoid the exception, you would have to pass in something like `new B("Johnson", "Smith")`, which can then be safely cast to `B` because it is an instance of `B`